# Shift array elements java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I've got Method to shift arr elements:

```
 private static int[] shiftElements(int[] arr, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i+n] = arr[i];
        }
        return arr;
    }

n - amount of shifting.
```

When I execute this code I've got an exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
```

As far as I understand program need more space to contain another item. But I don't need to added
more item, I need shift already existing. With `n`parameter, if parameter negative all array moving to left, if positive to right, if zero - nothing happen.

```
Examples


ORIGINAL ARRAY: 1,3,5,6,8,10

example: 
n = 2
arr: 8,10,1,3,5,6

How to achieve it?
```

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException speaks by itself.

Comment: For your example, `arr = [1,3,5,6,8,10]` and `n=2`, let `m = 6` equal the size of `arr`. The ith element of the new array `b` (`i = 0` indexing the first element) equals `arr[(i-n) % m]`, where `%` is the [modulus operator](https://www.edureka.co/blog/mod-method-in-java/#What_is_a_modulus_operator?). `b[0]` (`i=0`) equals `arr[(0-2) % 6] #=> arr[4] #=> 8`. Similarly, for `i = 4`, `b[4] = arr[(4-2) % 6] #=> arr[2] #=> 5`. Notice that if you want to modify the original array you will need to create a new array and then replace the original array with the new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception comes from this line:

```
arr[i+n] = arr[i];
```

You get an exception because i + n > arr.length.

From your example, you want those elements that would end up outside the array to be added at the front instead.

I won't do your homework for you, but you might want to use an `if(...)` for that. Or a `mod` expression...